# Rails/PostgreSQL: Adding character limit to text

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, text, character-limit

I want to implement a character limit to a data value on my PostgreSQL database for my Ruby on Rails application. Currently my database table looks like this:

```
create_table "applications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.date     "date_of_birth"
    t.string   "gpa"
    t.text     "essay"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
end
```

I want to change it so the "essay" only allows 10000 characters. From my limited understanding of PostgreSQL, text is unlimited by default whereas string is for 255 characters or less. I thought about implementing a Javascript conditional to not let the user hit the submission button in the client if the text is over 1,000 characters, but of course a tech savvy user could change that. What would be the most optimal way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, but did you mean 10000 or 1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rails model validations - [validates_length_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_length_of).

On the rails end you can add this in `application.rb` file

`validates_length_of :essay, :maximum => 1000`

This will ensure that max size is not exceded. Also keep the javascript validation, since its helpful for all users except the malicious once.

Also I recommend you to change the table name from `applications`. You can get easily confused

Comment: Model validations and database constraints are not interchangeable. Model validations can easily be by-passed if you use the proper method.